# How to handle ElementNotInteractableException selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

What I am trying to do is, to take the content from a currently opened web browser text field, edit it and paste back.
I can get the text like this:

```
def getText():
    text = chrome.find_elements_by_id("HTMLEditor")[0].get_attribute("value")
    return text
```

and it works fine.
But after changing the text, I do this:

```
def paste(text):
    chrome.find_elements_by_id("HTMLEditor")[0].send_keys(text)
```

in the function "paste", I get "element not interactable". I know the area `chrome.find_elements_by_id("HTMLEditor")[0]` is valid since I can get the text from there.

So what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, clicking the element before sending keys helps. Perhaps try something like:

```
def paste(text):
    WebDriverWait(chrome,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "HTMLEditor"))).click()
    chrome.find_elements_by_id("HTMLEditor")[0].send_keys(text)
```

WebdriverWait needs these imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: this time I get the same error on click line. Thanks for help

Comment: I tried that but this time it doesn't stop waiting. Thanks for help

Comment: Any chance you can share the link to the webpage?

Comment: It requires login but I can add a bit of html to question

Comment: That, and the calls to your functions please.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the content from the web browser text field the desired element needs to be **visible**, which satisfies in your case. Ideally, to copy the content you should induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
def getText():
    text = WebDriverWait(chrome, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "HTMLEditor")))[0].get_attribute("value")
    return text
```

Similarly, to paste the content, the desired element needs to be **interactable**. So, to copy the content you need to you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following solution:

```
def paste(text):
    WebDriverWait(chrome, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "HTMLEditor")))[0].send_keys(text)
```

- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```